# Vega-Lite Graph on iOS VoiceOver

Tags: ios, svg, accessibility, voiceover, vega

While making a visualization with Vega-Lite (using VegaEmbed in Vue), the outputted graphic is skipped in iOS using VoiceOver.  Every other screen reader seems to work.

I'm using the following spec:

```
{

            $schema: 'https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json',
            data: {
              name: 'simple_capacity',
                  "values": [
                    {"route": "C", "b": 22, 'hh24': "1999-01-02T12:00:00"},
                    {"route": "C", "b": 77, 'hh24': "1999-01-02T17:00:00"},
                    {"route": "C", "b": 44, 'hh24': "1999-01-02T14:00:00"},
                    {"route": "D", "b": 11, 'hh24': "1999-01-02T11:00:00"},
                    {"route": "D", "b": 22, 'hh24': "1999-01-02T12:00:00"},
                    {"route": "D", "b": 66, 'hh24': "1999-01-02T16:00:00"},
                    {"route": "E", "b": 88, 'hh24': "1999-01-02T18:00:00"},
                    {"route": "E", "b": 44, 'hh24': "1999-01-02T14:00:00"},
                    {"route": "E", "b": 77, 'hh24': "1999-01-02T17:00:00"}
                  ]
            },
           

            mark: {
              type: 'rect', tooltip: true
            },

            encoding: {

              // Y Axis
              y: {
                field: 'route', 
                type: 'nominal', 
              },


              x: {
                field: 'hh24',
                type: 'temporal',
                timeUnit: "hours",
              },


              color: {
                field: "b",
                type: "ordinal", 
                legend: null
              },

            },
          }
```

Is there a way to edit the svg roles directly in the Vega-Lite (or Vega) spec?  It seems as though heavy modifications of these roles has a positive effect in getting VoiceOver to read the outputted graphics

EDIT:

It seems like the role "graphics-symbol" on SVG tags caused iOS VoiceOver (MacOS is fine) to skip the graphics:

```
<path 
  aria-label="Route: 1 - Hour: 23:00; XXXXXXXX" 
  role="graphics-symbol" 
  aria-roledescription="rect mark" 
  d="M827.541,0h35.958v25h-35.958Z" 
  fill="#ddd"></path>
```

Removing the role attribute caused iOS VoiceOver to read the individual marks.

Comment: In case you need a way to bootstrap a solution for iOS, I used `path.removeAttribute('role')` for all path elements in my viz.  You'll need to await Vega before executing though.